# No wifi adapter found but drivers loaded correctly

Tags: networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I have a Tomahawk x570 with an Intel AX200 wifi card on it. Some how I can't get the wifi working. The wifi tab in Settings show only "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"

[image: no wifi adapter found]

but in dmesg I can clearly see that the driver has been loaded.[image: dmesg]

I'm on Ubuntu 21.04 since that has the 5.11 kernel I need for the Ethernet to work, But I would be happy to get the wifi working too. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well this is so confusing...
I spent hours on this, rebooting trying different drivers, trying all kind of stuff... And now when I post the question here, I make one reboot more and now it works. I have no idea what fixed it, but now it works...